# Is it possible to change trait's context to the type declared as its type parameter?

Tags: scala, traits

What I'd like to accomplish is something similar to this:

```
class Foo( val bar: String = "Hello!" ) extends MyTrait[ Foo ]

trait MyTrait[ T ] { self : T =>
 T.bar
}
```

Changing self : T to self : Foo obviously works, but MyTrait may extend another class that also has bar, so self : Foo isn't acceptable.

I'm probably going about this wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, structural type is what you need:

```
trait MyTrait {
  self: { val bar: String } =>
 def showBar = bar
}

class Foo(val bar: String) extends MyTrait
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! Is it possible to expose the fields in Foo to MyTrait _in_ Foo?

Comment: I am not quite understand your idea. I guess, your original solution with polymorphic trait was about it. My second guess, if you want more sophisticated (scala-way) dependency injection, take a look at [subcut](https://github.com/dickwall/subcut) library.

Answer (score 1):

It already works.

```
scala> trait Foo[A] { self: A =>
     | }
defined trait Foo

scala> class Meh extends Foo[Meh]
defined class Meh

scala> class Duh extends Foo[Meh]
<console>:36: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type Duh does not conform to Foo[Meh]'s selftype Foo[Meh] with Meh
       class Duh extends Foo[Meh]
                         ^
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, I misunderstood the question. @4e6 is right. You need a structural type. A slight variation of his solution:

```
scala> trait Foo[A <: { def bar: String }] { self: A =>
     | }
defined trait Foo

scala> class Bar extends Foo[Bar] {
     |   def bar = ""
     | }
defined class Bar

scala> class Baz extends Foo[Baz]
<console>:35: error: type arguments [Baz] do not conform to trait Foo's type parameter bounds [A <: AnyRef{def bar: Stri
ng}]
       class Baz extends Foo[Baz]
                         ^
```